# Line too long, how do I break a line within brackets

Tags: python-3.x

After reading PEP8 and editing my code this is what I came up with:

```
 class Wheel(object):
    """A Virtual Wheel"""
    def __init__(self, start_number, stop_number, input_number, rotation_units, direction):
        self.start_number = start_number
        self.stop_number = stop_number
        self.input_number = input_number
        self.rotation_units = rotation_units
        self.direction = direction
        self.output_number = 0
        self.verify = None
        self.circumference_units_sum = 0
```

## This is what I decided to use after reading PEP8:

```
class Wheel(object):
    """A Virtual Wheel"""
    def __init__(self, start_number, stop_number,
                 input_number, rotation_units, direction):
        self.start_number = start_number
        self.stop_number = stop_number
        self.input_number = input_number
        self.rotation_units = rotation_units
        self.direction = direction
        self.output_number = 0
        self.verify = None
        self.circumference_units_sum = 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure `number` is needed so much

Comment: Fair comment, thanks Peter

Comment: I tried to show what I had learned in an edit and present how my code now looks, this did not work out very well, as I just got one big line under the original question.  Sue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for much help and suggestions, I have learned much and have managed to present better on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, as long as you're within brackets (works with parentheses, square, and curly), you don't need any special handling. Simply write:

```
class Wheel(object):
    """A Virtual Wheel"""
    def __init__(self, start_number, stop_number, input_number, rotation_units,
                 direction):
       self.start_number = start_number
       self.stop_number = stop_number
       self.input_number = input_number
       self.rotation_units = rotation_units
       self.direction = direction
       self.output_number = 0
       self.verify = None
       self.circumference_units_sum = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the backslash character (`\`) to break up long lines, but between brackets you don't even need it (in fact, it's reported by pep8!), and could just break the line:. E.g.:

```
class Wheel(object):
    """A Virtual Wheel"""
    def __init__(self,
                 start_number,
                 stop_number,
                 input_number,
                 rotation_units,
                 direction):
        self.start_number = start_number
        self.stop_number = stop_number
        self.input_number = input_number
        self.rotation_units = rotation_units
        self.direction = direction
        self.output_number = 0
        self.verify = None
        self.circumference_units_sum = 0
```

Comment: thanks, that works in the spyder editor but still having trouble with Ninja, any  suggestions please.

Comment: @Susan what problems do you still have?

Comment: Loquacious suggested this -def __init__(self, start_number, stop_number, input_number, rotation_units,
                 direction):

Comment: After reading PEP8, I saw this:                                                                       # Aligned with opening delimiter.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
var_three, var_four)                                                                                             and decided I like it best, thanks everyone for your help to get me pythonic. Sue

Comment: class Wheel(object):
    """A Virtual Wheel"""
    def __init__(self, start_number, stop_number,
                 input_number, rotation_units, direction):
        self.start_number = start_number
        self.stop_number = stop_number
        self.input_number = input_number
        self.rotation_units = rotation_units
        self.direction = direction
        self.output_number = 0
        self.verify = None
        self.circumference_units_sum = 0

Comment: How does one get stuff to look Pythonic in the comments box, or is it just not possible?       Sue.

Comment: @Susan formatting is the comments if pretty limited. I suggest you edit your original post and add what you finally decided to use

Answer (score 1):

Python itself has no issues with your line length so I have to assume you just want it for the purposes of readability.

If that's the case, the first thing I'd look at is the variable names, you can shorten them quite easily without losing readability:

```
start_number   -> startNum/start_num
stop_number    -> stopNum/stop_num
input_number   -> inputNum/input_num
rotation_units -> rotUnits/rot_units
direction      -> direction
```

That would result in a reduction:

```
def __init__(self, start_number, stop_number, input_number, rotation_units, direction):
def __init__(self, start_num, stop_num, input_num, rot_units, direction):
def __init__(self, startNum, stopNum, inputNum, rotUnits, direction):
```

Beyond that, you can use `\` as a continuation character (or <kbd>newline</kbd> in this case) but I tend not to do that because it looks *uglier* to me and I prefer as much code on the screen as possible while reading.

Comment: This is not Pythonic though. According to PEP-8, identifiers should be `snake_cased`, not `camelCased`.

Comment: @Loquacious: you should read the entirety of PEP-8, particularly the bits in the intro stating it's the convention for the Python standard *library* and that it's perfectly acceptable for project-specific guidelines to override them. I actually prefer Camel case myself, I find it more readable (which puts me in the exception 1 area: "when applying the guideline would make the code less readable"). I converted from tabs to spaces many moons ago but I'm afraid you'll have to pry my beloved Camel case from my cold dead fingers :-)

Comment: I admit it's been nearly a decade since I last read PEP-8 in its entirety. Usually I reread just bits and pieces. The conventions are merely suggestions and not rules, but interpreters will warn about it and so will many co-developers.